# How to lookup heap usage for Websphere

Tags: websphere, heap-memory

I don't know much about WebSphere, but I need to know the **CONFIGURED** heap size for WebSphere.

I checked out with `ps -ef` and grep it by `WebSphere` hoping for Xms, Xmx to show up but could not see those arguments in the process result.  (`MaxPermSize` was listed, though)

How can I check the xms, xmx, and optionaly the current usage?
I way not using GUI is prefered, but if no easy way, then GUI is ok.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain this information with the [wsadmin](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=90-scripting-application-serving-environment-wsadmin) scripting tool. Specifically, the following Jython commands ([or download this file](https://github.com/dougbreaux/websphere/blob/master/getJvmHeap.py)) will do the trick:

```py
    server = AdminConfig.getid('/Server:yourServerName/')
    jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', server)
    
    print 'initialHeapSize: ' + AdminConfig.showAttribute(jvm, 'initialHeapSize')
    print 'maximumHeapSize: ' + AdminConfig.showAttribute(jvm, 'maximumHeapSize')
```

Edit: the above only shows you values you've explicitly configured. Here are alternate commands which will also show the value even if it's the JVM default:

```py
    jvmName = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:type=JVM,process=yourServerName,*')
    AdminControl.getAttribute(jvmName,'maxMemory')
```